# Edit suggestions reviewed with less than 2k reputation?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

To review "suggested edits" a reputation of 2k or more is necessary.
I never reached 2k but it still looks like I was able to review a couple of suggested edits.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: You can review suggested edits on your own posts.

Comment: Not a duplicate, target questions doesn't contain information that you can accept proposed edits on your own posts even if you don't have enough reputation for review, and it's counted as review action too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always review edits that are proposed on your own posts. Like these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2327920
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2902738